I need to restrict the player's movement around the area (map)
I have a map positioned in the center of the screen (not full screen). I need to restrict the character's movement so that he can't go off the map. The map has CollisionShape2D and Sprite2D.
The character also has CollisionShape2D and Sprite2D.
I wrote this code, but it doesn't work quite right (the X boundary is shifted to the right).
extends CharacterBody2D
const SPEED = 500.0
var width = 0
var height = 0

func _ready() -> void:
    var sprite = get_parent().get_node("Map").get_node('Sprite2D')
    var rect = sprite.get_rect()
    width = rect.size.x
    height = rect.size.y
    print("Width: ", rect.size.x, " Height: ", rect.size.y)

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    var direction: Vector2 = Vector2.ZERO
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        direction.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
    direction.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_down"):
    direction.y += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_up"):
    direction.y -= 1

    direction = direction.normalized()

    velocity = direction * SPEED

    move_and_slide()

    var map_position = get_parent().get_node("Map").position
    
    position.x = clamp(position.x, map_position.x - (width / 2), map_position.x + width / 2)
    position.y = clamp(position.y, map_position.y - (height / 2), map_position.y + height / 2)



if you use direction, velocity and move_and_slide to move your character, you shouldn't also change its position by hand in code. from your description im not sure how you setup the collision areas of your level but if you have level walls setup and the player has a collision shape. it should work when you removed the last two lines.
